# Copy over an XSLT attribute based on another attribute

Tags: xslt, key, tei

It seems to me that this should be an easy thing to do with `key` but I'm struggling.

I have two XML files with `<w>` elements with `<m>` elements within.

They both have a `@corresp` attribute and a `@sameAs` attribute, but one of the files has is missing a number of the `@sameAs` attributes.

I would like to copy over the missing `@sameAs` attributes from one file to the other with the assumption that the `@sameAs` value is paired with the `@corresp` attribute's value (they are English/Spanish translations).

Where a value for `@sameAs` already exists, I this should not be overwritten.

The `@sameAs` - `@corresp` pairs are valid across both `m` and `w`.

The input file looks like this:

```
<p>
    <w  pos="N" corresp="house" sameAs="casa/ruca"><m corresp="house"  sameAs="casa" type="root">ruca</m></w>
    <w  pos="N" corresp="man"><m corresp="man" type="root">wentru</m></w>
    <w  pos="AJ" corresp="bad"><m corresp="bad" type="root">weda</m></w>
    <w  pos="N" corresp="query"><m corresp="stone/rock" sameAs="piedra/roca" type="root">cura</m><m corresp="instrumental" type="suffix">we</m></w>
</p>
```

The output should be:

```
<p>
    <w  pos="N" corresp="house" sameAs="casa/ruca"><m corresp="house" sameAs="casa" type="root">ruca</m></w>
    <w  pos="N" corresp="man"  sameAs="hombre"><m corresp="man" sameAs="hombre" type="root">wentru</m></w>
    <w  pos="AJ" corresp="bad"  sameAs="malo(a)"><m corresp="bad" type="root" sameAs="malo(a)">weda</m></w>
    <w  pos="N" corresp="query"><m corresp="stone/rock" sameAs="piedra/roca" type="root">kura</m><m corresp="instrumental" type="suffix">we</m></w>
</p>
```

The lookup file looks like this:

```
<p>
    <w  pos="N" corresp="house" sameAs="casa"><m corresp="house"  sameAs="casa" type="root">ruka</m></w>
    <w  pos="N" corresp="dog" sameAs="perro"><m corresp="dog"  sameAs="perro" type="root">txewa</m></w>
    <w  pos="N" corresp="man"  sameAs="hombre"><m corresp="man"  sameAs="hombre" type="root">wentro</m></w>
    <w  pos="AJ" corresp="bad"  sameAs="malo(a)"><m corresp="bad" type="root" sameAs="malo(a)">wesha</m></w>
    <w  pos="N" corresp="query"><m corresp="stone/rock" sameAs="piedra/roca" type="root">kura</m><m corresp="instrumental" type="suffix">we</m></w>
</p>
```

I tried the following, but to no avail:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xpath-default-namespace="http://www.tei-c.org/ns/1.0"
    exclude-result-prefixes="#all"
    version="3.0">
    <xsl:param name="lookup-doc" select="document('lookup.xml')"/>
    <xsl:key name="ref" match="w/@sameAs|node()" composite="yes" use="@corresp"/>
    <xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-copy"/> 
    <xsl:template match="w/@sameAs|node()[key('ref', (@corresp, @sameAs), $lookup-doc)]">
        <xsl:copy-of select="w/@sameAs|node()[key('ref', (@corresp, @sameAs), $lookup-doc)]"/>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Any tips?

Comment: So you need to fix both the `w` and the `m` elements to add a missing `sameAs`? And the `sameAs` might not even be missing but could just be empty? Will the `corresp` values be unique and always the same for the `w` and its child `m`?

Comment: In your input file sample you have the element `<w  pos="N" corresp="house" sameAs="casa/ruca"><m corresp="house"  sameAs="casa" type="root">ruca</m></w>` where both the `w` and the `m` already have a `sameAs` attribute. Based on your textual description I wouldn't expect any change to that element, yet in your output the content of the `m` element has changed from `ruca` to `ruka`. Is the element content supposed to adapted to the one from the lookup file?

Comment: sorry, the ```ruka``` in the output was a typo.

Comment: the empty ```saveAs``` was also a typo. The input will not empty ```saveAs``` attributes, though it may have a ```saveAs``` with a value which should not be overwritten.

Comment: both the ```w``` and the ```m``` need to have a ```@sameAs```, if this is available in the lookup document. The ```@corresp``` – ```@sameAs``` pairs are valid across ```m``` and  ```w```. Sorry – I should have made that clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The textual description to copy `sameAs` attributes if they don't exist sounds like

```
<xsl:key name="ref" match="w" use="@corresp"/>

<xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-copy"/> 

<xsl:template match="w[not(@sameAs)][key('ref', @corresp, $lookup-doc)] | m[not(@sameAs)][key('ref', @corresp, $lookup-doc)]">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*, key('ref', @corresp, $lookup-doc)/@sameAs, node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: This worked a treat. Thanks so much. I can see my approach needed to negatively define the context for match.